# parse.com local datastore iOS: syncing changes from local datastore

Tags: ios, parse-platform

This is with reference to the *Syncing Local Changes* example in the iOS/OSX Guide, the code is:

```
PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"GameScore"];
[query fromPinWithName:@"MyChanges"];
[[query findObjectsInBackground] continueWithBlock:^id(BFTask *task) {
  NSArray *scores = task.result;
  for (PFObject *score in scores) {
    [[score saveInBackground] continueWithSuccessBlock:^id(BFTask *task) {
        return [score unpinInBackground];
    }];
  }
}];
```

my understanding is that it would take all the objects under the label `MyChanges` and will save them (if required, right?). Will it also properly delete objects that I may have marked for deletion via `deleteEventually()`?